# case statement same column

Tags: sql

have column that has values of total and hours inside it but I need to split the group into two columns
for example

```
select 
case
when A.TYPE = 'H'

then A.Value


end as "Hours",

Case 
when A.TYPE != 'H'
then A.VALUE

end as "Total" 

from a
```

what this is returning is 2 columns but doubling it not a lining values.

```
Hours     Total
  2        null 
null        20
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table would appear to have two rows.  If you want one row in the result set you need aggregation:

```
select max(case when A.TYPE = 'H' then A.Value end) as Hours,
       max(case when A.TYPE <> 'H' then A.VALUE end) as Total
from a;
```